# Flash Pro CC 15 not always adding all createjs script tags when published

Tags: flash, html5-canvas, createjs

I've noticed that when I create a new canvas file in flash and publish that file out that all of the script tags needed don't always seem to be added. For some reason it seems to not always add these tags:

```
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/tweenjs-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/movieclip-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
```

I try to set up my files, publish out and then turn the overwrite html option off. But it seems when I do this that not all the createjs files have been added. Does it only add these files when you start to write code? I'm not sure the process of how the script tags get added to the html file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It tries to optimize the included libraries to only those that are necessary for your export. So, if there are no multiframe MovieClip symbols exported, it does not include Tween and MovieClip.

Comment: Ahh so if you're going to use a lib like Greensock it would be best to create a MC before you turn the override off. Interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Or just replace the individual libraries with the combined CreateJS lib: https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.05.21.min.js